# Can Graphlib be used to generate GraphQL queries?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graphql

Graphlib is a JavaScript library for creating and **modifying** graphs.

- Graphlib Creates a JSON representation of the graph
- Graphlib Takes JSON as input and returns the graph representation.

**I wonder if it can be used to get and set data into a database or if it can generate a query.**

[graphlib/wiki](https://github.com/dagrejs/graphlib/wiki)

I wonder if it's possible to develop a middleware code which will make Graphlib utilities to interact with a GraphQL API? 
[image]
Otherwise, how can Graphlib be used if it is not able to change a database record?
Can graphlib help me somehow or do I have to implement my own utilities to generate GraphQL queries?

Comment: I think we are missing some information in here, what does it mean interact with GraphQL? Is just generating code? Or it means that any graphql code should update graphlib ?  
So what you want is to use graphlib as an ORM?

Comment: In fact, I want to know what's the actual use of a library like [Graphlib](https://github.com/dagrejs/graphlib/wiki). Well, it can get or set nodes and edges but data is not in a database. I wonder if it can be used to get and set data into a database or if it can generate a query. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Are you missing this part in between: https://github.com/walmartlabs/json-to-simple-graphql-schema ?